# Parse Simple Json response

Tags: java, android, json, youtube-api

Am trying to parse this Json response. For some weird reason its not working. Please bear with me . I really suck at Json.

[Here is the Url am trying to parse:](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/iS1g8G_njx8?v=2&alt=json)

This is the code am using to parse it:

```
      public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

       final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";

    // set your json string url here


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        String str = "";
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost myConnection = new   HttpPost("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/iS1g8G_njx8?v=2&alt=jsonc");

        try {
            response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
            str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try{
            JSONObject myJson = new JSONObject(str);

            String grande =  myJson.getString("title");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+grande, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } catch ( JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



         return null;
      }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }
   }
```

i just need to parse the Title and descrption only. thanks

Comment: What is the exception you are getting

Comment: what error u got during parsing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its seems you have not parsed properly

Change your try block with the following code

```
try{
            JSONObject myJson = new JSONObject(str);
            JSONObject entityObject = myJson.getJSONObject("entity");

            // Parsing title
            JSONOBject titleObject = entityObject.getJSONObject("title");
            String grande =  titleObject.getString("$t");

            // Do the same for Description as well (Like above two line)

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+grande, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } catch ( JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that toast message of yours (in doInBackground) is posing problems, try commenting it out and then check!

Moreover, best practice is to send the response to onPostExecute as an argument and then parse the Json in onPostExecute

Comment: @Srinivas B are my parsing the Json correctly?.if am sure i parsed it correctly then i'll try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        String str = "";
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost myConnection = new   HttpPost("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/iS1g8G_njx8?v=2&alt=jsonc");

        try {
            response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
            str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         return str;
      }

       @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        try{
            JSONObject myJson = new JSONObject(result);

             JSONObject entry =  results.getJSONObject("entry");
            JSONObject grande =  results.getJSONObject("title");
            String title =  grande.getString("$t"); 
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } catch ( JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }
```